# HttpClient cancellation doesn't inform server of cancellation

Tags: c#, web-services, httpclient, cancellation-token

I'm trying to create a client for an OWIN web service that informs the service if a request is cancelled, so the service can cancel the currently ongoing work for this request as well.

On the server-side I have an ApiController with this method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Get")]
public int Get(CancellationToken ct)
{
  Console.WriteLine("started!");

  while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(500);
  }

  Console.WriteLine("canceled!");

  return 0;
}
```

If I access the API via Edge, it works (I get the "canceled!" message as soon as I abort loading, navigate somewhere else, close the tab or close the browser), but with every other method I tried (Chrome, Postman, HttpClient, HttpWebRequest), the CancellationToken just won't be canceled. What does Edge do different than all the other applications and what can be done to get it to work with HttpClient? I tried to call GetAsync() with a CancellationToken and cancel it, I tried to the Dispose() and the CancelPendingRequests() methods of HttpClient, but none of them triggered a server-side cancellation.

Comment: I just updated the Nuget packages for Owin and now it seems to work. Will post an answer later, if I can confirm that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After updating the Nuget packages

```
Microsoft.Owin
Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener
Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
Microsoft.Owin.SelfHost
```

to v3.1.0, cancellation works as expected not only from Edge, but also from Chrome and HttpClient. I downgraded the packages to v2.0.0 again to rule out other causes and can confirm that the newer versions solved the problem. I'm still curious to why it worked in Edge even before the upgrade, though.